# Point in Polygon Algorithm in Programming Contests

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, point-in-polygon

What is the best algorithm to solve point in polygon in programming contests?

Comment: There are optimized algorithms for most of the common shapes (namely triangles and quadrilaterals), but a simple approach is outlined by Wikipedia that should work for any arbitrary polygon as long as you choose the ray properly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: -1 You want to enter a computational geometry contest - but are asking the community solve it for you!?

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion cmannett85??!!

Answer (score 1):

Shoot a ray(in arbitrary direction) from the point and check the number of times it has crossed the edges of polygon if it is even then the point is outside the polygon otherwise the point is inside the polygon.

If you need to do it for lots of query points, you can triangulate the polygon (actually triangulate both inside and the region between the polygon the convex containing it) so that you could do ray shooting in O(log n)

Answer (score -1):

if you have a convex polygon you can use this :

http://e-maxx.ru/algo/pt_in_polygon